# PHP Fatal error: Class 'App\\User' not found in /home/e/eraser/domains/domain.com/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php on line 100

Tags: laravel

The registration form is not working. I get this error in Apache Error Log...

`RegisterController.php` error in line return User::create([:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

**auth.php :**

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you changed the namespace of the user model you also have to update your `use` statement at the top of the `RegisterController` file

Change this

```
use App\User;
```

to this

```
use App\Models\User;
```

Comment: Thnaks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've left this file alone from the default generated with the Laravel project creator, at the top of `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php` you should see this line:

```
use App\User;
```

Change it to this:

```
use App\Models\User;
```

You should also grep the rest of your project directory for this change.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `RegisterController.php` file, and
update this

```
use App\User;
```

to

```php
use App\Models\User;
```

then go to `User.php` and update the namespace
from

```
namespace App;
```

to

```
namespace App\Models;
```

by the way, don't forget to move `User.php` file to `Models` directory that you have created

Hope this helps

Comment: Thnaks for your time!